# Custom Progress bar or Seekbar or animation?

Tags: android

I need to create some progress bar without dialog like this:
[image]

I could not find how to create custom progress bar and use it in main activity (not in dialog). This red bar consists of 2 small images and I need to add them continuously while my thread is working.
Now What is the way to do it ? 
Maybe it is better to use animations ?
Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a ProgressBar widget.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" />
```

and as progressbar drawable e.g.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerColor="#AA444444"
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:endColor="#88000000"
            android:startColor="#88000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF44"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#FFAAAA00"
                android:startColor="#FFAAAA00" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#FF88FF88"
                android:centerY="0.5"
                android:endColor="#FF44AA44"
                android:startColor="#FF44AA44" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

and for updates from your thread, post a runnable with `progressbar.setProgress()` or `progressBar.setSecondaryProgress()`, or even better, use an `AsyncTask` and call `publishProgress` and receive the calls in `onProgressUpdate()`

Comment: How to create that xml?
Do I have to put your code in <resources> tags?
I have some errors in xml...

Comment: Updated it, the formatting was messed up. You have to put that file in the drawable folder. If the drawable folder doesn't exist you have to create it.

Comment: nice it works!
now how can I use my images for creating the bar?
and the second question every time I need to call setProgress to update my bar ?

Comment: <clip> has a android:drawable attribute, this is the place afaik. And everytime you need a progress update, you call setProgress(). Set max() before.